# CRON settings to execute past midngith

Tags: cron

I am trying to get my CRON job to run Monday-Friday, every two hours between 1PM and 3AM at 37 minutes past the hour.

I tried:

```
37 13-03/2 * * 1-5 php /home/code/mytest.php
```

But it did not run.

If I do:

```
37 13-23/2 * * 1-5 php /home/code/mytest.php
```

It works fine, but it obviously does its last run at 11:37PM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your 1st line wont work; numbers need to be in sequence.

- You can always use 2 lines: 1 from 13:00 up to 24:00 and one from 00:00 to 03:00.

  ```
  37 00-03/2 * * 1-5 php /home/code/mytest.php
  37 13-00/2 * * 1-5 php /home/code/mytest.php
  ```
- You can write out all the hours comma separated.

  ```
  37 13,15,17,19,21,23,01,03 * * 1-5 php /home/code/mytest.php
  ```

(I hope I assumed the hours correctly).